# Limiting grid line length in combined TimelinePlots

Tags: grid-lines, plotting

I am trying to make a complex `TimelinePlot` in which temporal periods are indicated as shaded areas (using `Filling -> Axis`) while individual events and their durations are indicated by simple bars (using `Filling -> None`).  As far as I can see, there is no way to specify `Filling-> {Axis, Axis, None, None}` and so forth in `TimelinePlot`, which would allow me to specify the temporal periods and the individual events in the same `TimelinePlot`, so I've resorted to making two separate `TimelinePlots` and integrating them through `Show`.  Unfortunately, this leads to `GridLines` that are excessively long (high).  Alas, there is no option for specify the lengths of `GridLines` (through `GridLineStyle` for instance).

Here's the detailed timeline of events:

```
test1 = TimelinePlot[
  {{Labeled[{2016, 5, 3}, "aaa"], Labeled[{2017, 5, 3}, "bbb"],
    Labeled[{2020, 1, 1}, "ccc"]},
   {Labeled[Interval[{{2016, 1, 1}, {2016, 6, 15}}], "ddd"], 
    Labeled[Interval[{{2016, 3, 1}, {2016, 9, 15}}], "eee"],
    Labeled[Interval[{{2016, 9, 5}, {2017, 3, 15}}], "fff"],
    Labeled[Interval[{{2017, 1, 1}, {2017, 3, 15}}], "ggg"]},
   {Labeled[Interval[{{2017, 4, 15}, {2018, 1, 1}}], "hhh"],
    Labeled[Interval[{{2018, 4, 15}, {2019, 1, 1}}], "iii"]},
   {Labeled[Interval[{{2019, 4, 15}, {2019, 8, 1}}], "jjj"],
    Labeled[Interval[{{2019, 7, 15}, {2019, 12, 15}}], "kkk"],
    Labeled[Interval[{{2016, 4, 15}, {2019, 3, 1}}], "lll"]}},
  PlotRange -> {{{2016, 1, 1}, {2020, 1, 15}}},
  GridLines -> {DateRange["2016", "2020", Quantity[3, "Months"]], 
    None},
  GridLinesStyle -> {{Dashed, LightGray}, None},
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Orange, Blue, Red},
  Spacings -> {1, 8, 8},
  FrameStyle -> Italic,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{None, "Lab 1", "Lab 2", "Lab 3"}, Bottom],
  ImageSize -> 700]
```

and here is `TimelinePlot` for the desired background:

```
test2 = TimelinePlot[
  {{Labeled[Interval[{{2016, 1, 1}, {2016, 12, 30}}], "Stage 1"]},
   {Labeled[Interval[{{2017, 1, 1}, {2017, 12, 30}}], "Stage 2"]},
   {Labeled[Interval[{{2018, 1, 1}, {2018, 12, 30}}], "Stage 3"]},
   {Labeled[Interval[{{2019, 1, 1}, {2019, 12, 30}}], "Stage 4"]}},
  PlotRange -> {{{2016, 1, 1}, {2020, 1, 15}}},
  GridLines -> {DateRange["2016", "2020", Quantity[3, "Months"]], 
    None},
  GridLinesStyle -> {{Dashed, LightGray}, None},
  PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[.4, .7, 0], RGBColor[.6, .7, 0], 
    RGBColor[.8, .9, 0],  RGBColor[1, 1, 0]},
  Spacings -> {100, 0, 0, 0},
  Filling -> Axis,
  FrameStyle -> Italic,
  ImageSize -> 700]
```

Each of these looks fine, when presented alone.

When I integrate them, however, I get:

```
Show[test2, test1, AspectRatio -> .7]
```

[image]

As you can see, the `GridLines` extend far too high.

I've tried all manner of `Spacings`, `AspectRatios`, inclusion of `GridLines` in one plot by not another, order of plots in `Show`, failed explorations of `PlotRange`, and so forth, but none prune the `Gridlines` to a reasonable height.

How can I create a full `TimelinePlot` in which the `GridLines` are an appropriate height?

Answer (score 7):

After lots of experimentation, I found that one can use `PlotRangePadding` with a negative argument for the top line to crop the whole figure.  This is a hack, but it works.  It would be great to see how to achieve the proper figure in a more principled manner.

Comment: (+1) Did not know that `PlotRangePadding` accepts negative values.

Answer (score 6):

Specifying explicit vertical `PlotRange` helps:

```
Show[test2, test1, AspectRatio -> .7,  
 PlotRange -> {All, {0, 133.5}}, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

> [image: plot]

The correct value for `PlotRange` can be found by switching on the `Frame`:

```
Show[test2, test1, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> True]
```